# How i can delete all files.txt in vbs

Tags: vbscript

How i use this code to delete all files with extension .txt
all text files in my P.C
*.txt

any one help me to Re-write this code

```
Option Explicit

Const DeleteReadOnly = True 
Dim oFSO, oDrive, sFileName

Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sFileName  = "g.txt"

For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives 
  If oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then Recurse oDrive.RootFolder
Next 

Sub Recurse(oFolder)
  Dim oSubFolder, oFile

  If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
     Recurse oSubFolder
    Next 

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      If oFile.Name = sFileName Then
        oFile.Delete ' or whatever
      End If
    Next 
  End If
End Sub

Function IsAccessible(oFolder)
  On Error Resume Next
  IsAccessible = oFolder.SubFolders.Count >= 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an IF block to check the extension, delete if it is **txt**.

`If oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile) = "txt" Then`

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your script to do an extension check:

```
Option Explicit

Const DeleteReadOnly = True 
Dim oFSO, oDrive, sFileExt

Set oFSO   = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
sFileExt = "txt"

For Each oDrive In oFSO.Drives 
  If oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then Recurse oDrive.RootFolder
Next 

Sub Recurse(oFolder)
  Dim oSubFolder, oFile

  If IsAccessible(oFolder) Then
    For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
      Recurse oSubFolder
    Next 

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      If lcase(oFSO.GetExtensionName(oFile)) = lcase(sFileExt) then
        oFile.Delete ' or whatever
      End If
    Next 
  End If
End Sub

Function IsAccessible(oFolder)
  On Error Resume Next
  IsAccessible = oFolder.SubFolders.Count >= 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Dim oDrive

For Each oDrive In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").Drives 
  If oDrive.DriveType = 2 Then 
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "cmd /c del /s /q " & Chr(34) & oDrive.RootFolder.Path & "*.txt" & Chr(34), 0, True
  End If
Next
```